# find unknowns with periodic

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-calculus, periodic-functions, eigenfunctions

find the value of c such that the system will have periodic solution
$$\overrightarrow x'(t)=\begin{pmatrix} 
3 & -9\\
c & -3\\
\end{pmatrix}\overrightarrow x(t)
$$

I found the eigenvalues det(A-λt), $$λ= \pm 3 \sqrt{1-c}$$
and then I tried to find the eigenvector for the positive eigenvalue
$$\begin{pmatrix}
3-3 \sqrt{1-c} & -9\\
c& -3-3 \sqrt{1-c}\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$ multiply with 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
V_1\\
V_2\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$ equal 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
 I am not sure how to find three unknowns here and not sure what the question means by periodic solutions.

Comment: You only have two unknowns because the eigenvector can be scaled by any factor.  Your unknowns are $c$ and $\frac {V_1}{V_2}$

Comment: do you know what it means by periodic solution?

Comment: Why did you vandalize the question?  It had a lot more useful information before.  A periodic solution is one that repeats after a given time, like a sine wave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a different approach. Again we'll write $A$ for the system matrix.  Begin by conjugating $A$ with an elementary matrix to obtain a matrix with zeros on the diagonal:
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cr} 1 & 0 \\ -1/3 & 1\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{cr} 3 & -9 \\ c & -3\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{cr} 1 & 0 \\ +1/3 & 1\end{array}\right) =
\left(\begin{array}{cr} 0 & -9 \\ c-1 & 0\end{array}\right)
$$

Conjugate this with a diagonal matrix in order to make the off diagonal elements equal with opposite signs:
$$
\left(\begin{array}{cr} \sqrt{c-1} & 0 \\ 0 & 3\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{cr} 0 & -9 \\ c-1 & 0\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1/\sqrt{c-1} & 0 \\ 0 & 1/3\end{array}\right) =
\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & -3\sqrt{c-1} \\ 3\sqrt{c-1} & 0\end{array}\right)
$$

Writing $\omega$ for $3\sqrt{c-1}$, we see that your system matrix is conjugate to the skew matrix
$$\Omega =\left(\begin{array}{cr} 0 & -\omega \\ \omega& 0\end{array}\right)$$

So the entries in the solution vector to your differential equation are linear combinations of the entries in the solution vector to the equation
$$
\vec{y}'(t) = \Omega\; \vec{y}(t)
$$
It's not hard to see that 
$$
\vec{y(t)} = 
\left(\begin{array}{c} \cos(\omega t)  \\  \sin(\omega t) \end{array}\right)
$$
is a solution, and it will be a **periodic solution** if **$\bf\omega$ is real**.  Which holds whenever $c$ is greater than 1.

Answer (score 1):

You're writing $A$ for the system matrix 
$\left(\begin{array}{cr} 3 & -9 \\ c & -3\end{array}\right)$.

The system has periodic solutions --- solutions in which each component of the
state vector is a real linear combination of $\sin(\omega t)$ and $\cos(\omega t)$ for some positive real number $\omega$ --- exactly when the eigenvalues of $A$ are nonzero and purely imaginary. This is true whenever the real number $c$ is greater than 1.  For in this case the eigenvalues of $A$ are $i\omega$ and $-i\omega$ with $\omega =3\sqrt{c-1}$, the matrix $A$ is similar to a diagonal matrix whose nonzero entries are $i\omega$ and $-i\omega$, and the matrix exponential $\exp(At)$ is similar to a diagonal matrix whose nonzero entries are $e^{i\omega t}$ and $e^{-i\omega t}$.

Your system has periodic solutions if $c$ is any real number greater than 1.